# How can i save settings of my app to a text file and read them back on load?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Read them back in app constructor and also maybe in other places in program.
I have a new form i created with some checkboxes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Options
{
    public partial class OptionsMenuForm : Form
    {


        public OptionsMenuForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                Settings.downloadonstart = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Settings.downloadonstart = false;
            }
        }

        private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                Settings.loadonstart = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Settings.loadonstart = false;
            }
        }

        private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox3.Checked)
            {
                Settings.startminimized = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Settings.startminimized = false;
            }
        }

        private void checkBox4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox4.Checked)
            {
                Settings.displaynotifications = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Settings.displaynotifications = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want to save each time the state of one/any of the checkboxes.
I also added a class i'm using th pass the variables between the new form and form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Options
{
    class Settings
    {
        public static bool downloadonstart;
        public static bool loadonstart;
        public static bool startminimized;
        public static bool displaynotifications;
    }
}
```

Now how can i use this in form1 by saving the settings to a text file ?
For example in the text file the content will be something like:

```
CheckBox1 = true
CheckBox2 = false
CheckBox3 = false
CheckBox4 = true
```

And then if i change the state of one of them it will write it in the text file:

```
CheckBox1 = false
CheckBox2 = false
CheckBox3 = true
CheckBox4 = true
```

In form1 top i added

```
string settingsFile = "settings.txt";
string settingsFileDirectory = "\\settings";
StreamWriter writetosettingsfile;
```

Then in constructor

```
settingsFileDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) +
                settingsFileDirectory;
            if (!Directory.Exists(settingsFileDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(settingsFileDirectory);
            }
```

I know the app it self have a settings in the properties but i wanted to use a text file this time since i have many settings and i might have more later.

Or using the settings in the app in properties i did:

[image: Settings]

But now how do i use with it in my program to save every checkbox state in the new form and then using it in form1 ?

Comment: Either use an .ini file Architecture. Where .INI file is used usually for Settings or use either XML,JSON and parse them. Don't go with the normal text format, where you constantly need to ReadLines. Just a tip. Can't answer your question until you choose how to save your file.

Comment: Aizen in this case i prefer to learn using the .INI file.

Comment: My problem is also how to save each checkbox state ? In the new form i'm checking each checkbox if its true or false so i need to save in each event there the two states in the IF and in the ELSE ? Or somehow i can save the checkbox states in one place in the code ?

Comment: I would use a `ConfigurationManager` to write XML files. INI files are a thing of the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public OptionsMenuForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //Read the settings from a file with comma delimited 1's and 0's or whatever you like
    string[] values = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("c:\temp\a.txt").Split(',');
    checkBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(values[0]));
    checkBox2.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(values[1]));;

    //On checkbox changes save the settings
    checkBox1.CheckedChanged +=SaveSettings;
    checkBox2.CheckedChanged +=SaveSettings;
}

public void SaveSettings(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sbValues = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;

    i = checkBox1.Checked ? 1 : 0;
    sbValues.Append(i.ToString() + ",");

    i = checkBox2.Checked ? 1 : 0;
    sbValues.Append(i.ToString() + ",");

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("c:\temp\a.txt",sbValues.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Jeremy something wrong with the convertion to bool. In this line: checkBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(values[0]); i see that the first value in values is "1" and then i'm getting exception on the line: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean and the text file content is: 1,0,0,1,

Comment: See if you can figure it out (without looking), if you cant, then see my revised answer.

Comment: Yes found it. I needed to convert it to Int inside the bool convert first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use json.net

Something like this to save the data

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkBox1.CheckedChanged += checkBox_CheckedChanged;
    checkBox2.CheckedChanged += checkBox_CheckedChanged;
    checkBox3.CheckedChanged += checkBox_CheckedChanged;
    checkBox4.CheckedChanged += checkBox_CheckedChanged;
}

private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var settings = new Settings();
    settings.downloadonstart = checkBox1.Checked;
    settings.loadonstart = checkBox2.Checked;
    settings.startminimized = checkBox3.Checked;
    settings.displaynotifications = checkBox4.Checked;
    File.WriteAllText(@"c:\configfile.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settings));
}
```

You can read the file like this

```
Settings settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\configfile.json"));
```

Documentation: 
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm

Comment: This is good, I like this approach, similar to old skool **.ini** files, but you didn't explain how to save the settings on each checkbox change. Good luck on SO], a good tip is to put in a thorough effort with [mcve]'s, it will pay dividends as most points you earn are from people in the future seeing complete well written answers.

Comment: @JeremyThompson thank you, I edited the answer to add the part of saving the settings on each checkbox change

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended that you use XML when using the .NET framework.

```
public static void ConvertStringToXmlList()
{
    XElement xml = new XElement
        (
            "Items",
            (
                from x in [YourList] select new XElement("Item", x)
            )
        );
    XDocument doc = new XDocument
        (
            xml
        );
    doc.Save(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/settings.xml");  
}



var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader("settings.xml");
while (xmlReader.Read()) 
{
    switch (reader.NodeType) 
    {
       case [nodetype]:
           // Code here
       break;
    }
}
```

Also, instead of creating the same event for all four checkbox's, just use 1.

Inside of the single event put:

```
ckCheckBox1.Checked = !ckCheckBox1.Checked;
```